# which data-structure would be suitable for this problem

Tags: data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, a-star

I need to implement bfs, dfs and a* algorithm in any language and compare them.
for comparison I need a test case and the Input I need to give is this road map below. I can't understand how should I input this road map in my program.
suggest an approach to program these algorithm using this road map to find the shortest path.

I expect the output to give the shortest path of the road map from ARAD to BUCHAREST.

ROAD MAP

[image]

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-graph-using-dictionary-python/) and [this](https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php) might help you.

Comment: This question will answer itself as soon as you start researching how those algorithms work. The answer is "using a graph"

Comment: I would suggest using an adjacency list to keep track of your edges. Where each edge is a road/path that connects 2 destinations which are the nodes.
For BFS - use a queue. 
For DFS - use a recursion / stack approach.
Both the algorithms will run in O(m+n)

Comment: A quick search yields [lots of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ARAD+to+BUCHAREST)